# Changing the path of a video in VideoView

Tags: android

Currently I am setting the video path of a video view like this;

```
"android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videoName
```

however I want to be able to change videoName by selecting names of the video files from an array that was generated from the file in R.raw.

what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: add switch condition for an array. because I don't think you can use this R.raw in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

One way I worked out to do it was by setting the path like this, where **path** is a String variable taken from a array.get(position).

```
vidPath = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + "/raw/" + path;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 2 videos.

```
int videoArray[]={R.raw.videoName1,R.raw.videoName2};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
button1 = ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1));
button2 = ((Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2));
button1.setOnClickListener(this);
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
VideoView vv = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
         String uriPath = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/raw/"+videoArray[0];
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
         vv.setVideoURI(uri);
         vv.start();
      break;
    case R.id.button2:
         String uriPath = "android.resource://"+  getPackageName() + "/raw/"+videoArray[1];
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriPath);
         vv.setVideoURI(uri);
         vv.start();
      break;
}
```

Comment: That is changing the video depending on button clicked?